# "Safari Web Content" process uses loads of memory even with a single tab open

Tags: macos, memory, safari

When looking at OS X **Activity Monitor** under the "Real Mem" column, I frequently find a process called "Safari Web Content" using 1gig+ of memory.  I understand that this happens when I open a lot of tabs.  However, even after I close essentially all the tabs, I find it is still very high.  I have to restart Safari to bring it back down to reasonable levels.  Is there a way to make Safari release this memory while leaving Safari open?

Comment: Have you tried disabling or removing all 3rd party browser extensions?

Comment: According to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2910, it might be caused by Flash or it might just be an instance of "free memory is wasted memory".

Comment: Look on StackExchange for many discussions of this problem. What it boils down to is waiting for an Apple memory-management fix, and using one of the memory freer little menubar apps, or the purge command if preferred. The Click-To-Flash Safari extension can help, but after a lot of reading, people just manually release inactive RAM as needed. Turning off Safari's cache and DNS prefetching have helped some people.